# External component has thrown an exception. ASP.NET ASPX PAGE POST

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have an `aspx` page that communicates with a webservice I have. It connects to an `SQL Server` database on my virtual dedicated server. With just a little usage, I get this error

> External component has thrown an
>   exception.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException:
>   External component has thrown an
>   exception.`
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
>    Luxand.FSDK.Initialize(String DataFilesPath) +0
>    WebService.onLoad() +70
>    WebService..ctor() +91
>    facematch.btn_submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +218
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +105
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +107
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +7
>    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +11
>    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +33
>    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1746
> ```

I also get this one too:

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +725754
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnData() +88
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout) +223
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i) +17
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values) +181
   System.Data.ProviderBase.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values) +10
   System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow() +30
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping) +137
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue) +153
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords) +283
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +221
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +162
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +107
   Dataservice.getProfile() +110
   facematch.btn_submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +97
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +107
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +7
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +11
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +33
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1746

Answer (score 1):

That means that the following method threw an exception:

```
Luxand.FSDK.Initialize(String DataFilesPath)
```

Could you figure out what is in `DataFilesPath`? Maybe something isn't configured right?

Or otherwise something must be wrong with that `Luxand.FSDK` library. I suppose that's a COM component? Is it registered properly? Does it have all the user rights it needs?

Or maybe the component just isn't able (or configured) to run in a multi threaded environment (which ASP.NET is)?

Comment: Well the website works fine unless I use it a few times meaning unless I submit the information a few times.

Comment: @Brandon: Wow that seems like an `OutOfMemoryException` while reading something from the database. Hmmm has this app ever run before? In another environment?

Comment: I havent had a chance to try it in another environment but is this a database issue? if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure... might also be an issue with how the app reads the data. Could you try to figure out what exactly it tries to query and try that query manually on the database?

Comment: well I also have an application that adds information to the database and this application stops in the middle and gives me a "External component has thrown an exception." So I'm thinking it might be a database issue right? what should I try to do please?

Comment: Concerning the database issue, see my comment above; try to query it manually. That "external component has thrown an exception" issue is something COM related. Unless that COM component also queries the same database, I don't think these issues are related.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to do that.